# .htaccess redirect only if GET parameter exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a client with an old website without 'pretty' URLs. So currently it looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/?w=42&a=5&b=3
```

The parameter values are numbers only.

Now they want to move the old site to a subdomain and main (www) domain would be home to a new website (WP with SEO friendly URLs).

Now what I would like to do is redirect all requests that come to the `/?w=<num>` (and ONLY those) to `sub.domain.com/?w=<num>`, so that existing links (mostly from Google) get redirected to the subdomain page, while the new page works serving new content thorough pretty URLs.

I tried this:

```
# This works, but redirects the entire www.domain.com
# to sub.domain.com no mather what 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# But this DOESN'T work
RewriteRule   ^/?w(.*)  http://sub.domain.com/?w$1  [R=301,L]

# Also tried to redirect 'by hand', but DIDN'T work either
Redirect 301 /?w=42 http://sub.domain.com/?w=42
```

What am I doing wrong? I searched high and low but always end up with this kind of suggestions. Or maybe I'm just searching for wrong keywords ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't match against the query string inside a rewrite rule or a redirect directive. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)w=[0-9]+(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that the query string gets automatically appended to the end of the rule's destination.

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you! 

After some testing, this also works if the parameters are reversed, but not, if `w=` is missing altogether.

Just to clarify, if I also wanted to do it for other letters (ie. some links have only `a=` and `b=` parameters):

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)c=[0-9]+(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)w=[0-9]+(&|$)`

Is this the right way?

Comment: @IamJ you can just me 1 condition: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(w|a|b)=[0-9]+(&|$)` for w=, a=, or b=.

Answer (score 3):

Just for documentation: If you want to redirect one directory (path) only if there is a URL parameter present, from one path to another, while maintaining the URL parameter, you can use this in your htaccess file:

```
# /programs/?id=1 to new path /loadprog/?id=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/programs/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=
RewriteRule ^programs\/$ /loadprog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am sure this will help others since I stumbled over the question above trying to find this answer.