# Apache directory index on demand

Tags: apache

Within Apache, how can I call the default directory index creator on-demand?

Here's the situation. Requirement is to display, say, a default image file for a URL that corresponds to a directory. That's easy to do, using mod_dir. But a further requirement is that, when the image is clicked (in the browser), display a directory listing. Now I realize that can be done by writing some directory-listing code (in PHP, say). But that seems like re-inventing the wheel. So ideally I'd like to invoke the code in mod_autoindex directly.

Answer (score 0):

This may well not be possible at all.

One *possible*, untested approach that may be worth a try:

- Set up `DirectoryIndex` as you have it now
- Build a [conditional URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903223/htaccess-redirect-only-if-get-parameter-exists) that is fired on the directory index, but only if a certain GET parameter - let’s say `showlist`- is *not* set to `yes`. For how to write a `RewriteCond` that checks for GET parameters in URLs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903223/htaccess-redirect-only-if-get-parameter-exists). To address only directories, use

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  ```
- If that condition is not met, have `RewriteRule` redirect to the page with your image. That way, when I open a directory on your server, I will be taken to that page.
- On the page with the image, have a link to the directory with the GET parameter specified:

  > http://my.domain/directoryname/?showlist=yes

  That *should* not redirect back to the file with the image, but display Apache’s directory listing.